# Python: How to break the special character ' ; '?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I break down `;` in order to count the number of `Fruit`?

The dataframe looks like the following:

```
     ID         Fruit
0    123       <apple>;<orange>;<lemon>;<pear>
1    456       <lemon>;<lemon>;<lemon>;<kiwi>
2    789       <orange>;<apple>;<kiwi>;<apple>
```

Expected Result:

```
apple:  3
orange: 2
lemon:  4
pear:   1
kiwi:   2
```

Comment: Hint: `"<apple>;<orange>;<lemon>;<pear>".split(';') == ["<apple>", "<orange>", "<lemon>", "<pear>"]`.

Answer (score 6):

In your case `split` then `explode` + `value_counts`

```
out = df.Fruit.str.split(';').explode().value_counts()
Out[163]: 
<lemon>     4
<apple>     3
<kiwi>      2
<orange>    2
<pear>      1
Name: Fruit, dtype: int64
```

To make it match your output `str.strip('<|>')`

```
df.Fruit.str.split(';').explode().str.strip('<|>').value_counts()
Out[164]: 
lemon     4
apple     3
orange    2
kiwi      2
pear      1
Name: Fruit, dtype: int64
```